# Intent at startup

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to write this snippit into my onCreate method. But the issue I think is that when the program is first opened it will not have this intent sent to it. It is basicly so I can navigate from the home screen to another and when you come back it changes accordingly. At the moment though on startup it forces the application to close.

```
Intent inten = getIntent();
Bundle b = inten.getExtras();
int newText = b.getInt("NEXTQUESTION");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just check if `b` is null? something like:

```
int newText;
if(b == null) {
    newText = FIRSTQUESTION;
} else {
    newText = b.getInt("NEXTQUESTION");
}
```

anyway if I understood well, it's going to pile up a lot of activities in the [task stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask), because you're not `finish()`'ing them, but calling every time a new one, right? I don't know if it's good:

> For the default "standard" mode, a new
>   instance is created to respond to
>   every new intent.

Comment: How do i finish the intent / instance. If i finish it does that mean i cant use the back button to go to the previous page? Basiclly my app at the moment will have two pages. One asks a question the other tells the result. From the result page it reloads the question page with a new question and so it continues. Im new so do not know best practices. Thanks for any extra help

Comment: @Max see if this can fit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)

Comment: Thanks that looks like it will be really useful.